# NP-полнота задачи "самый длинный цикл"

Tags: алгоритм

Дан неориентированный граф, для каждого ребра известен его вес (положительное целое число).
Также дано положительное целое число K.
Требуется ответить на вопрос: существует ли в графе такой цикл, что сумма весов ребер, входящих в этот цикл, не меньше K.

Как я понимаю, для доказательства необходимо свести к этой задаче Гамильтонов цикл, а именно по входным данным для гамильтонова цикла построить входные данные для поставленной задачи.
Для этого я рассмотрела K = n, где n - это количество вершин в графе. Веса всех ребер взяты равные 1. А множество ребер и вершин в этих двух задачах одинаковые.
Тогда в одну сторону доказательство очевидное (если есть гамильтонов, то есть и самый длинный). А в обратную совсем не понятно что делать.

Скорее всего я ошибаюсь со сводимостью, и нужно брать не одинаковые множества вершин и ребер в обоих этих задачах. Но пока что не получается придумать адекватного построения.

Может есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: А что именно вы хотите _доказать_? В первом абзаце речь идёт лишь о задаче, в которой нужно _найти_.

Comment: Вы хотите доказать NP-полноту этой задачи?

Comment: да, то что она принадлежит классу NP доказать получилось, а дальше возникли проблемы

Comment: Так а вам и не нужна эквивалентность по идее. Достаточно доказать, что произвольный Гамильтонов цикл сводится к вашей задаче. Разве нет? А это вы уже сделали. Значит, ваша задача не проще Гамильтонова цикла. А раз Гамильтонов цикл NP-полон, то и ваша задача тоже

Comment: Формально: раз Гамильтонов цикл NP-полон, то любая NP-задача сводится к нему за полиномиальное время. А раз ваша задача NP, то и она сводится к Гамильтонову циклу (и вам не интересно, как именно, главное, что сводится). С другой стороны, вы доказали, что и Гамильтонов цикл сводится к вашей задаче.

Comment: не совсем ведь. Чтобы доказать, что задача NP-полная, мне нужно 1. показать, что она из класса NP. 2 что к ней можно полиномиально свести какую-нибудь уже известную задачу.

Comment: Ну так вы ж свели к ней Гамильтонов цикл. Это всё, что надо, правильно? Или ещё не свели?

Comment: а полиномиальная сводимость подразумевает, что существует некоторая функция, которая из входных данных известной задачи делает входные данные для требуемой задачи и при этом существование решения в известной есть тогда и только тогда, когда существует решение нужной задачи.

Comment: при моей же сводимости я могу доказать существование решения только в одну сторону.

Comment: Подождите, а цикл в вашей задаче имеет право проходить несколько раз через одну и ту же вершину?

Comment: да, кроме первой вершины (цикл не является простым по условию)

Comment: Ага, тогда всё сложнее, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, в английском варианте это задачи предполагается простой цикл.

Comment: Ааааа! А то я так и не придумал :)